# Using img's src as the source of the content in jQuery FancyBox 3

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox-3

I am using FancyBox 3 jQuery plugin and overall it is great. Works perfectly with my website, but there is an usual case where the anchor links that wraps the images on a webpage has a `href`that points to an URL that is not an image but a link to another site or web page, so FancyBox 3 opens it instead of the image inside the anchor.

My HTML looks like this

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com" data-test="//3.bp.blogspot.com/-j6n4gYgWNvo/Vak3aiAi-zI/AAAAAAAAFtI/nIYEfDY74kEd97Gdkc6elifEOSz1yhBTQCPcB/s250/photo-1423683249427-8ca22bd873e0%2B%2528Medium%2529.jpg">
    <img src="//3.bp.blogspot.com/-j6n4gYgWNvo/Vak3aiAi-zI/AAAAAAAAFtI/nIYEfDY74kEd97Gdkc6elifEOSz1yhBTQCPcB/s250/photo-1423683249427-8ca22bd873e0%2B%2528Medium%2529.jpg">
  </a>
```

I have added a data attribute `data-test` to see if I can get FancyBox to fetch the URL inside of it as the source URL (if `data-test` exists for that anchor)

My JS code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body img').parent("a").fancybox({
  opts: {
            prevEffect  : 'none',
            nextEffect  : 'none'
    }
  });
});
```

I did nothing special. What I tried was to set the source using the `beforeLoad` callback like  this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body img').parent("a").fancybox({
  href: $(this).find("img").attr('data-test'),
  opts: {
            prevEffect  : 'none',
            nextEffect  : 'none'
    }
  });
});
```

But `$(this).find("img").attr('data-test')` doesn't appear to work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here or if there is some other approach which is more standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-src` attribute to set custom source.

But the point of the script is that you put small version of the image (thumbnail) inside anchor pointing to real one.

Comment: My need on the website is to only display the images so `data-src` works great for me, thank you for pointing it out! Not sure where it was hidden in the docs. Thanks!